# Bigquery error (ASCII 0) encountered for external table and when loading table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting this error
"Error: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 4824. Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered."

The data is not compressed.
My external table points to multiple CSV files, and one of them contains a couple of lines with that character. In my table definition I added "MaxBadRecords", but that had no effect. I also get the same problem when loading the data in a regular table.

I know I could use DataFlow or even try to fix the CSVs, but is there an alternative to that does not include writing a parser, and hopefully just as easy and efficient?

Comment: See if one of these can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274168/big-query-load-fails-with-bad-character-ascii-0-while-importing-datastore-back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632859/bad-character-ascii-0-encountered-while-importing-data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021610/big-query-job-fails-with-bad-character-ascii-0-encountered

Answer (score 6):

> is there an alternative to that does not include writing a parser, and hopefully just as easy and efficient?

Try below in Google Cloud SDK Shell (with use of [`tr`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tr/info) utility)

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket/badfile.csv - | tr -d '\000' | gsutil cp - gs://bucket/fixedfile.csv
```

This will

1. Read your "bad" file
2. Remove ASCII 0
3. Save "fixed" file into new file

After you have new file - just make sure your table now points to that fixed one

Comment: Hi Mikhail. I have a few questions: what if the filenames for the old file and the new one are the same? And how slow can it be considering that the GCS bucket gets synced with some FTP server every hour, so the syncing process will overwrite the files and I would have to run this after? I had tried using the sed command, but since it had to run on all files every time it synced, it was very slow and since the filenames are the same I got an error saying that the resource was busy,

Comment: you can just simply try to overwrite old file with extracted ascii 0 and see how it will work for you :o) - just try. as of hourly process - honestly i havn't considered this scenario as I thought it is just one off case with kind of bad file - but still you can try to make that fixing process as a part (last step) of your syncing with ftp. it is hard to judge about how fast/slow it will be as it depends on multiple factors  - again the only way is to try and experiment with your files and see if it will be working or not

Comment: but actually, before even considering having this trick as a part of your hourly syncing with ftp - I think you should first check if this actually works and fix the issue! can you try and confirm? as this is mostly the scope of your question :o)

Comment: it was a bit too slow for me for the larger files, so I decided to do what 
 was avoiding, I wrote a dataflow pipeline that does the importing from a schema

Comment: @Jordan - makes sense!

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant.. is there no other way to get rid of this.. like using some bigquery functions or something else on the fly

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it occurs that a final byte appears in file.

What could help is replacing it thanks to :

```
tr '\0' ' ' < file1 > file2
```

Comment: this seemed to give me a garbled mess in my `.csv` file afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can clean the file using an external tool like python or PowerShell. There is no way to load any file with an ASCII0 in bigquery

This is a script that can clear the file with python:

```
def replace_chars(self,file_path,orignal_string,new_string):
    #Create temp file
    fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
    with os.fdopen(fh,'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_file:
        with open(file_path, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as old_file:
            print("\nCurrent line: \t")
            i=0
            for line in old_file:
                print(i,end="\r", flush=True)
                i=i+1
                line=line.replace(orignal_string, new_string)
                new_file.write(line)
    #Copy the file permissions from the old file to the new file
    shutil.copymode(file_path, abs_path)
    #Remove original file
    os.remove(file_path)
    #Move new file
    shutil.move(abs_path, file_path)
```

The same but for PowerShell:

```
(Get-Content "C:\Source.DAT") -replace "`0", " " | Set-Content "C:\Destination.DAT"
```