# BigQuery Load error - Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 0. Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, ascii, directed-acyclic-graphs

Facing issue - "google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 0. Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered" while trying to load a BigQuery native table through an Airflow DAG.

Read somewhere that this is with UTF encoding. Can someone please help with the same.

Comment: In my case, I had to remove a bad character (\000) using `trim -d \000` in bash script and then uploaded into BigQuery.  How about considering add a task in your DAG to pre-process CSV file ?


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616844/bigquery-error-ascii-0-encountered-for-external-table-and-when-loading-table?rq=1